# Can I use a 2D photo to get a 3D printing model?

Tags: 3d-models, graphics

Can I use a 2D photo to get a 3D printing model that gives a good result?

Comment: Rather depends on what you want for a result.  For example, look up "lithopane" for one specific application of a 2D photo to a printable item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just 1 2D photo, you can never get a 100% accurate 3D object. That is because you don't really know about the hidden parts.  Think of a photo of a smiling mischievous child that is facing you, and you can't see that they are holding a sling shot behind their back.    However, with multiple 2D photos, one can reconstruct a 3D object, provided all the parts are seen.  This is called photogrammetry.  You can search wikipedia and youtube for in-depth discussion about this.  It is an entire science.  There are applications that do this for you, but I can't recall the details right now.